# Fast way to check container exit status

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

I need a fast way to check if a containers has exited in a scriptable way. Currently using docker library with python but that creates too much overhead.

`docker inspect -f {{.State.Status}} $CONTAINER_PID` 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it by using the subprocess package (the `shell=True` is important):

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(r"docker inspect -f {{.State.Status}} $CONTAINER_PID", shell=True).decode()

print(output)
```

Comment: You should try really hard to avoid `shell=True` since it opens you up to a range of security issues; combined with Docker commands, it's really easy to use this to root the host.  Try `os.environ['CONTAINER_PID']` in the array-form, if that's how things are getting passed in.  (Or, even if the questioner would prefer not to, using the Docker Python SDK would be preferable to shelling out.)